# why tar creating a link

Tags: tar

```
root@linux:/mnt/TEST# ls
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt
root@linux:/mnt/TEST# find /mnt/TEST/ -mmin -10 -exec  tar -czvf /tmp/test.tar.gz {} +
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/mnt/TEST/
/mnt/TEST/test3.txt
/mnt/TEST/test2.txt
/mnt/TEST/test1.txt
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
/mnt/TEST/test3.txt
/mnt/TEST/test2.txt
/mnt/TEST/test1.txt
root@linux:/mnt/TEST# tar -tvf /tmp/test.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/test3.txt
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/test2.txt
-rw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/test1.txt
hrw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/test3.txt link to mnt/TEST/test3.txt
hrw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/test2.txt link to mnt/TEST/test2.txt
hrw-r--r-- root/root         0 2017-10-08 00:15 mnt/TEST/test1.txt link to mnt/TEST/test1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You include the files twice, and GNU `tar` notices and assumes that the second set of files, since they have the same inode as the first set, must be hard links.

You archive them twice:

1. First by archiving the `/mnt/TEST` directory (which fulfill the `find` criteria),
2. and then again by archiving the individual files.

You should modify your `find` command to only find regular files:

```
find /mnt/TEST/ -type f -mmin -10 -exec  tar -czvf /tmp/test.tar.gz {} +
```

---

Also note that if the `find` command finds more files than can may be handled by a single invocation of `tar`, it will call `tar` multiple times, overwriting the tar archive each time.

Fixing this:

```
find /mnt/TEST/ -type f -mmin -10 \
    -exec sh -c 'a="/tmp/test.tar.gz"; if [ -f "$a" ]; then tar -uzvf "$a" "$@"; else tar -czvf "$a" "$@"; fi' sh {} +
```

This will *append* files to the archive if the archive exists (`tar -u`), otherwise it will create the archive (`tar -c`).

Comment: didn't work. &  what if /mnt/TEST  contains any subdirectory?

Comment: @zim Had a typo (fixed now).  `find` will recurse into subdirectories, but I'm assuming you're only interested in calling `tar` with the actual _file paths_, not with the directories.

Comment: @zim You either use `find` to find files to archive, or you use it to find directories to archive. If you try to do both, then you and up with file included multiple times.

Comment: still links are there,  wanted  to create a tar file that include  all  files, directories under /mnt/TEST

Comment: @zim Hmm... Then why do you use `find` at all? `tar -cvzf /mnt/test.tar.gz /mnt/TEST` would do that.

Comment: @zim Also, I really can't reproduce the links in the archive if I use `-type f`... What command are you running?

Comment: find /mnt/TEST/ -mmin -10 -exec  tar -czvf /tmp/test.tar.gz {} + this is the command  i am using .  even if i  use option  -type f , hard links are also creted. tar -version  (GNU tar) 1.28.

Comment: @zim I'm sorry, but they can't be created when you use `-type f` before `-exec`: `find /mnt/TEST/ -type f -mmin -10 -exec  tar -czvf /tmp/test.tar.gz {} +`, unless you _have_ actual hard links in there.

Comment: @zim Ah, I see what's happening. You use `-mmin -10` and if no file has been modified in the last 10 minutes, the `tar` command won't even be executed, leaving the archive as it was (with hard links).

Comment: @zim Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).